# Initializing an array of instance variables

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm making a game with a Board class Cell class. The Board class needs to be initialized with a unique instance variable for each Cell. I can hardcode it so that it works, but it seems inelegant and doesn't allow the size of the board to be chosen by the user at runtime. Here's what I have:

```
class Board
  def initialize
    @cell_1 = Cell.new(1)
    @cell_2 = Cell.new(2)
    @cell_3 = Cell.new(3)
    @cell_4 = Cell.new(4)
    @cell_5 = Cell.new(5)
    @cell_6 = Cell.new(6)
    @cell_7 = Cell.new(7)
    @cell_8 = Cell.new(8)
    @cell_9 = Cell.new(0)
    @cells = [@cell_1, @cell_2, @cell_3,
              @cell_4, @cell_5, @cell_6,
              @cell_7, @cell_8, @cell_9]
  end
end
```

I think I could use a loop to create a hash with unique key names pointing to unique Cell objects, but I don't know how I could make unique *instance variables* with a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to create each instance variables (`@cell_1, @cell_2, ...`), you can use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org//core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
@cells = [*1..8, 0].map { |i| Cell.new(i) }
```

Comment: I actually had been referring to each instance variable by their names and for some reason thought I needed to. It turns out I didn't. When I tried this and then switched the references (eg. `@cells[0]` instead of `@cell_1`), it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to refer every instance variable by name you can do something like this.

```ruby
class Board
   def initialize
     @cells = (1..9).to_a.map { |i| Cell.new(i) }
   end

   def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
     if method =~ /^cell_[1-9][0-9]*$/
       index = method[/\d+/].to_i
       @cells[index-1]
     else
       super
     end
   end
end
```

In this way you can call:

```
board = Board.new
board.cell_1 #=> first cell
```

Of course I'd use the solution proposed by @falsetru.